# Numpy: Get all row and column combinations of a given matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Is there any easy way I can get with numPy (or any other python library) the combination of rows an columns of a given matrix?

For example if I give this matrix:

```
A = np.array(
[1,2,3],
[4,5,6],
[7,8,9]
)
```

I would get an array like this ( With all possible equivalent matrixes )

```
A = np.array(
[1,2,3],
[4,5,6],
[7,8,9]
)
RESULT =[ 
[
[1,2,3],
[4,5,6],
[7,8,9]
],
[
[4,5,6],
[1,2,3],
[7,8,9]
],
[
[4,5,6],
[7,8,9],
[1,2,3]
],
[
[7,8,9],
[4,5,6],
[1,2,3]
],
[
[8,7,9],
[4,5,6],
[1,2,3]
],
..
..
etc
]
```

Comment: Does this mean that you want 9!=362880 matrices?

Comment: I'm trying to use it to make a small script that given a matrix it finds it's strict diagonally dominant equivalent, so if it does not exist,  yes, it may evaluate 9! matrixes, but I think it will find one before checking all possibilities (if it exists).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `itertools`:

```
import itertools

for item in itertools.permutations(A.reshape(9), 9):
    print(np.array(item).reshape(3,3))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, short and simple!

Comment: I was testing the algorithm and it works great. I was just wondering if there is a way to limit the combinations so the columns are moved on all the rows the matrix and not just in one?

Comment: @PabloEstrada Sorry I don't quite get your question. Do you want to keep all the columns unchanged, and only the relative position of the columns are changed? Like `[[1,2],[3,4]]` and `[[2,1],[3,4]]`.

Comment: Hello. What I was trying to say is if I change the ith column, the change is reflected on all rows. There are no column changes allowed in just on row. The example would be [[1,2],[3,4]] and [[2,1],[4,3]] (Changed the column on each of the rows)

Comment: @PabloEstrada Try this: `for item in itertools.permutations(np.arange(A.shape[1])):
    print(A[:, item])`

Comment: Im sorry the change did work but it now ignores permutations for entire rows(without changing columns)

Comment: @PabloEstrada If you also want permutations for rows, you need to do another loop: `for item in itertools.permutations(np.arange(A.shape[0])): 
    print(A[item, :])` Combining the two `for` loops will give you what you want.